# Can't access localhost, error checking apache status

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I'm running Linux Mint Maya. When I enter `http://localhost/` in my browser, I get an "unable to connect" message. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling apache but that didn't work. When I enter `sudo service apache2 status` in the terminal, I get `/etc/init.d/apache2: 51: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars`

Here is the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ maya main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise partner

# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb games
```

When I run the Update Manager I've been getting an error but I didn't think it mattered so I've been ignoring it.  Here's the error:

```
There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/heyarje/libav-       11/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/heyarje/libav-11/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got apache working.  I'm not entirely sure how but I think it had something to do with running update distro.  After that I was able to run the same commands as recommended before and, this time, they worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a conflict with old configuration files. Try :

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: That didn't fix it. I get the same error messages.

Comment: What is the result of `ls -l /etc/apache2/envvars `?

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` then the two commands in my answer.

Comment: Still a no-go.  I ran the update, upgrade, purge, and install but I still get this:  
`ls: cannot access /etc/apache2/envvars: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?